# Weblogic ojdbc jar not compatible for Oracle OCI driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am able to run a standalone java code to connect to Oracle database using OCI driver.

It works only on ojdbc6.jar from my local oracle client in below location C:\app\client\jjayarman\product\12.1.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar

The same code fails with below error when it runs in a web app deployed on Weblogic 12c on my locahost because of its existing ojdbc jar.

Error: "javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path"

Should I replace all the ojdbc jars in the weblogic with the working ojdbc6.jar.

Is there any clean solution available ?

I am using Weblogic 12c, Oracle Database 12c, Windows 7 64Bit, Java 1.7

Many Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you miss some libraries in the production environment..

Have you checked this link?

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2319271